# Update Database Entry Displayed in Fragment Listview by Dialog

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-alertdialog, sqliteopenhelper

I have a `Fragment` that displays a `Listview` which is populated with entries from a `Database` using `SQLiteOpenHelper`. I currently have `ContextMenu` that allows entries to be deleted or edited. The `DELETE` option functions and removes the entry from my `Database`, however the `EDIT` option only takes the fields entered in the `Dialog` and adds a new entry to the `ListView`. I want to be able to attribute the values as provided by the dialog to the entry already existing in the `Database`. Thanks in advance for any input or advice.

Fragment:

```
   public static class FragmentS extends Fragment {

    private ListView saveListView;
    private List<LiftSave> LiftSaves = new ArrayList<LiftSave>();
    private static final int EDIT = 0, DELETE = 1;

    LiftSave longClickedItemLiftSave;
    DatabaseHandler dbHandler;
    ArrayAdapter<LiftSave> saveAdapter;

    public FragmentS() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_s,
                container, false);
        saveListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.saveListView);
        registerForContextMenu(saveListView);
        DatabaseHandler dbHandler;
        dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler (getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        if (dbHandler.getLiftSavesCount() != 0)
            LiftSaves.addAll(dbHandler.getAllLiftSaves());

        populateList();

        saveListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                longClickedItemLiftSave = (LiftSave) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                return false;
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    private void populateList() {
        saveAdapter = new SaveListAdapter();
        saveListView.setAdapter(saveAdapter);
    }


    public class SaveListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LiftSave> {
            public SaveListAdapter() {
                super(getActivity(), R.layout.listview_item, LiftSaves);
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
                if (view == null)
                    view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);

                LiftSave currentLiftSave = LiftSaves.get(position);

                TextView liftName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.liftName);
                liftName.setText(currentLiftSave.getLiftName());
                TextView maxValue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.maxValue);
                maxValue.setText(currentLiftSave.getMaxValue());
                TextView liftNotes = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.liftNotes);
                liftNotes.setText(currentLiftSave.getLiftNotes());
                TextView weightAndReps = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.weightAndReps);
                weightAndReps.setText(currentLiftSave.getRepsAndWeight());
                TextView date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.todayDate);
                date.setText(currentLiftSave.getTodayDate());

                return view;
            }

    }
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, view, menuInfo);

        menu.setHeaderIcon(R.drawable.pencil_icon);
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Save Options");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, EDIT, menu.NONE, "Edit Save");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, DELETE, menu.NONE, "Delete Save");
    }

    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case EDIT:
                final View dialogViewEdit = LayoutInflater.from(this.getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.edit_save, null, false);
                final AlertDialog builderE = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity()).create();

                TextView liftName = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.liftName);
                TextView maxValue = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.maxValue);
                TextView weightAndReps = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.weightAndReps);
                TextView liftNotes = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.liftNotes);
                TextView date = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.todayDate);

                final EditText editName = (EditText) dialogViewEdit.findViewById(R.id.liftNameED);
                editName.setText(liftName.getText().toString());
                EditText editNotes = (EditText) dialogViewEdit.findViewById(R.id.liftNotesED);
                editNotes.setText(liftNotes.getText().toString());
                EditText editWR = (EditText) dialogViewEdit.findViewById(R.id.txtWRED);
                editWR.setText(weightAndReps.getText().toString());
                EditText editMax = (EditText) dialogViewEdit.findViewById(R.id.txtMaxED);
                editMax.setText(maxValue.getText().toString());
                EditText editDate = (EditText) dialogViewEdit.findViewById(R.id.txtDateED);
                editDate.setText(date.getText().toString());

                Button cancel =(Button) dialogViewEdit.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
                Button save =(Button) dialogViewEdit.findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
                cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                    builderE.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        final EditText editName = (EditText) dialogViewEdit.findViewById(R.id.liftNameED);
                        EditText editNotes = (EditText) dialogViewEdit.findViewById(R.id.liftNotesED);
                        EditText editWR = (EditText) dialogViewEdit.findViewById(R.id.txtWRED);
                        EditText editMax = (EditText) dialogViewEdit.findViewById(R.id.txtMaxED);
                        EditText editDate = (EditText) dialogViewEdit.findViewById(R.id.txtDateED);
                        //Problem
                        dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                        LiftSave liftSave = new LiftSave(dbHandler.getLiftSavesCount(), String.valueOf(editName.getText()), String.valueOf(editMax.getText()), String.valueOf(editNotes.getText()), String.valueOf(editWR.getText()), String.valueOf(editDate.getText()));
                        LiftSaves.add(liftSave);
                        dbHandler.getLiftSave(longClickedItemLiftSave.getId());
                        dbHandler.updateLiftSave(longClickedItemLiftSave);
                        saveAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        //Problem
                    }
                });
                builderE.setView(dialogViewEdit);
                builderE.show();
                break;
            case DELETE:
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity());
                builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this save?")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                                dbHandler.deleteLiftSave(longClickedItemLiftSave);
                                saveAdapter.remove(longClickedItemLiftSave);
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog dialogD = builder.create();
                dialogD.show();
                break;
                            }
                            return super.
                            onContextItemSelected(item);
                        }
        }
```

Database:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "saveManager",
        TABLE_SAVES = "saves",
        KEY_ID = "id",
        KEY_LIFTNAME = "liftName",
        KEY_MAXVALUE = "txtMax",
        KEY_LIFTNOTES = "txtNotes",
        KEY_REPSANDWEIGHT = "repsAndWeight",
        KEY_TODAYDATE = "todayDate";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SAVES + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_LIFTNAME + " TEXT," + KEY_MAXVALUE + " TEXT," + KEY_LIFTNOTES + " TEXT," + KEY_REPSANDWEIGHT + " TEXT," + KEY_TODAYDATE + " TEXT)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_SAVES);

    onCreate(db);
}

public void createLiftSave(LiftSave liftSave) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_LIFTNAME, liftSave.getLiftName());
    values.put(KEY_MAXVALUE, liftSave.getMaxValue());
    values.put(KEY_LIFTNOTES, liftSave.getLiftNotes());
    values.put(KEY_REPSANDWEIGHT, liftSave.getRepsAndWeight());
    values.put(KEY_TODAYDATE, liftSave.getTodayDate());

    db.insert(TABLE_SAVES, null, values);
    db.close();
}

public LiftSave getLiftSave(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_SAVES, new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_LIFTNAME, KEY_MAXVALUE, KEY_LIFTNOTES, KEY_REPSANDWEIGHT, KEY_TODAYDATE }, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null );

    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    LiftSave liftSave = new LiftSave(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5) );
    db.close();
    cursor.close();
    return liftSave;
}

public void deleteLiftSave(LiftSave liftSave) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_SAVES, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(liftSave.getId()) });
    db.close();
}

public int getLiftSavesCount() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_SAVES, null);
    int count = cursor.getCount();
    db.close();
    cursor.close();

    return count;
}

public int updateLiftSave(LiftSave liftSave) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_LIFTNAME, liftSave.getLiftName());
    values.put(KEY_MAXVALUE, liftSave.getMaxValue());
    values.put(KEY_LIFTNOTES, liftSave.getLiftNotes());
    values.put(KEY_REPSANDWEIGHT, liftSave.getRepsAndWeight());
    values.put(KEY_TODAYDATE, liftSave.getTodayDate());

    int rowsAffected = db.update(TABLE_SAVES, values, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(liftSave.getId()) });
    db.close();

    return rowsAffected;
}

public List<LiftSave> getAllLiftSaves() {
    List<LiftSave> liftSaves = new ArrayList<LiftSave>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_SAVES, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            liftSaves.add(new LiftSave(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5)));
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return liftSaves;
}
}
```

LiftSave:

```
public class LiftSave {

private String _liftName, _maxValue, _liftNotes, _repsAndWeight, _todayDate;
private int _id;

public LiftSave(int id, String liftName, String maxValue, String liftNotes, String repsAndWeight, String todayDate) {
    _id = id;
    _liftName = liftName;
    _maxValue = maxValue;
    _liftNotes = liftNotes;
    _repsAndWeight = repsAndWeight;
    _todayDate = todayDate;
}



public int getId() { return _id; }

public String getLiftName() {return _liftName;}

public String getMaxValue() {return _maxValue;}

public String getLiftNotes() {return _liftNotes;}

public String getRepsAndWeight() {return _repsAndWeight;}

public String getTodayDate() {return _todayDate;}

}
```

Comment: Can you post your `LiftSave` class?  I think I see a way to fix this.

Comment: @DanielNugent Class is up. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:  One way to solve it after I just saw your `LiftSave` class.
With this fix, you wouldn't have to modify the `DatabaseHandler` class at all:

```
                //Problem
                dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

                //pass in the existing ID instead of dbHandler.getLiftSavesCount()
                LiftSave liftSave = new LiftSave(longClickedItemLiftSave.getId() , String.valueOf(editName.getText()), String.valueOf(editMax.getText()), String.valueOf(editNotes.getText()), String.valueOf(editWR.getText()), String.valueOf(editDate.getText()));

                //LiftSaves.add(liftSave); //Don't add to the list here
                //dbHandler.getLiftSave(longClickedItemLiftSave.getId()); //looks like this is not needed

                //pass in the LiftSave object with existing ID and new values
                dbHandler.updateLiftSave(liftSave);

                LiftSaves.clear(); //Remove all entries from the list
                LiftSaves.addAll(dbHandler.getAllLiftSaves()); //Re-add all records to List including modified entry
                saveAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                //Problem
```

Note that `longClickedItemLiftSave.getId()` is passed in as the `id` for the new `LiftSave`, so when you pass it into `updateLiftSave()` it updates the original entry.

Initial proposed solution, another way to solve it:

First, make your `updateLiftSave()` method take an `id` as a parameter, and update the record with that `id`:

```
public int updateLiftSave(LiftSave liftSave, int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_LIFTNAME, liftSave.getLiftName());
    values.put(KEY_MAXVALUE, liftSave.getMaxValue());
    values.put(KEY_LIFTNOTES, liftSave.getLiftNotes());
    values.put(KEY_REPSANDWEIGHT, liftSave.getRepsAndWeight());
    values.put(KEY_TODAYDATE, liftSave.getTodayDate());

    //int rowsAffected = db.update(TABLE_SAVES, values, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(liftSave.getId()) });
    int rowsAffected = db.update(TABLE_SAVES, values, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });

    db.close();

    return rowsAffected;
}
```

Then, when updating, use the original `id` and the new values:

```
                        //Problem
                        dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                        LiftSave liftSave = new LiftSave(dbHandler.getLiftSavesCount(), String.valueOf(editName.getText()), String.valueOf(editMax.getText()), String.valueOf(editNotes.getText()), String.valueOf(editWR.getText()), String.valueOf(editDate.getText()));
                        //LiftSaves.add(liftSave); //don't add it do the list
                        //dbHandler.getLiftSave(longClickedItemLiftSave.getId()); //looks like this is not needed
                        dbHandler.updateLiftSave(liftSave, longClickedItemLiftSave.getId()); //pass in the new values and the existing ID

                        LiftSaves.clear(); //Remove all entries from the list
                        LiftSaves.addAll(dbHandler.getAllLiftSaves()); //Re-add all records to List including modified entry
                        saveAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        //Problem
```

Update:  You might also need to add a call to clear the list in `onCreateView()` in order to ensure that you never get duplicate entries in the List, and that the List always mirrors the entries currently in the database:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       //........
        if (dbHandler.getLiftSavesCount() != 0){
            LiftSaves.clear();  //Clear the list just in case
            LiftSaves.addAll(dbHandler.getAllLiftSaves());
        }
```

Update 2:  As for your last issue, try using the `LiftSaves` List instead of the `parent` AdapterView:

```
saveListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //longClickedItemLiftSave = (LiftSave) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                longClickedItemLiftSave = LiftSaves.get(position);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: I elected to use your Edit solution and its working great. However, in order to see the updated data I have to restart the app. Previously it was instantaneous with `saveAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); ` (effectively a refresh function?). Has something changed?

Comment: Additionally, if more than one item is on the list, and one is chosen to be edited, a new entry is created in the same fashion as my initial problem.

Comment: Thank for bearing with me.

Comment: It persists unfortunately even with the addition of `LiftSaves.clear();                      LiftSaves.addAll(dbHandler.getAllLiftSaves()); saveAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); `. The update now is immediate to the `ListView`, however when you navigate away from the `Fragment` and to it again the original entry (that was updated) is followed by its original version, as well as a duplicate of any other items on the list.

Comment: It did, thank you so much!  Do you have an idea as how to ensure that the text provided to the `Dialog` is that of the item long clicked? Currently it is taking the `String` values of the first entry for all other items selected as well (I haven't figured how to locate position if that whats needed). Either way I'm ecstatic, going to mark your answer here in just a few minutes. Can't thank you enough.

Comment: It appears to still get the same values (first entry `String`s).

Comment: @Austin Put a log entry in there to make sure it's getting in that code every time the ContextMenu is opened. If you can't get it figured out, post a new question, and I'll take another look at it!

Comment: Haha got confused. Check out the new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29585315/set-edittext-of-dialog-to-value-of-listview-item-onitemlongclick