# Set EditText of Dialog to value of ListView Item onItemLongClick

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog, android-contextmenu, onitemlongclicklistener

I have a `ListView` within a `Fragment` that has a `ContextMenu` to edit and delete entries. The `ContextMenu` launches a `Dialog` on selection of the `EDIT` option. I'd like to set the `EditText`'s of that `Dialog` to the `String` values of the item selected via `onItemLongClick` on the `ListView`, but have been unable to do so. Thanks in advance.

Fragment:

```
    public static class FragmentS extends Fragment {

    private ListView saveListView;
    private List<LiftSave> LiftSaves = new ArrayList<LiftSave>();
    private static final int EDIT = 0, DELETE = 1;

    LiftSave longClickedItemLiftSave;
    DatabaseHandler dbHandler;
    ArrayAdapter<LiftSave> saveAdapter;

    public FragmentS() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_s,
                container, false);
        saveListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.saveListView);
        registerForContextMenu(saveListView);
        DatabaseHandler dbHandler;
        dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler (getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        if (dbHandler.getLiftSavesCount() != 0)
            LiftSaves.clear();
            LiftSaves.addAll(dbHandler.getAllLiftSaves());

        populateList();

        saveListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                longClickedItemLiftSave = LiftSaves.get(position);
                return false;
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    private void populateList() {
        saveAdapter = new SaveListAdapter();
        saveListView.setAdapter(saveAdapter);
    }


    public class SaveListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LiftSave> {
            public SaveListAdapter() {
                super(getActivity(), R.layout.listview_item, LiftSaves);
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
                if (view == null)
                    view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);

                LiftSave currentLiftSave = LiftSaves.get(position);

                TextView liftName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.liftName);
                liftName.setText(currentLiftSave.getLiftName());
                TextView maxValue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.maxValue);
                maxValue.setText(currentLiftSave.getMaxValue());
                TextView liftNotes = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.liftNotes);
                liftNotes.setText(currentLiftSave.getLiftNotes());
                TextView weightAndReps = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.weightAndReps);
                weightAndReps.setText(currentLiftSave.getRepsAndWeight());
                TextView date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.todayDate);
                date.setText(currentLiftSave.getTodayDate());

                return view;
            }

    }
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, view, menuInfo);

        menu.setHeaderIcon(R.drawable.pencil_icon);
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Save Options");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, EDIT, menu.NONE, "Edit Save");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, DELETE, menu.NONE, "Delete Save");
    }

    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case EDIT:
                final View dialogViewEdit = LayoutInflater.from(this.getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.edit_save, null, false);
                final AlertDialog builderE = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity()).create();

                TextView liftName = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.liftName);
                TextView maxValue = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.maxValue);
                TextView weightAndReps = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.weightAndReps);
                TextView liftNotes = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.liftNotes);
                TextView date = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.todayDate);

                EditText editName = (EditText) dialogViewEdit.findViewById(R.id.liftNameED);
                editName.setText(liftName.getText().toString());
                EditText editNotes = (EditText) dialogViewEdit.findViewById(R.id.liftNotesED);
                editNotes.setText(liftNotes.getText().toString());
                EditText editWR = (EditText) dialogViewEdit.findViewById(R.id.txtWRED);
                editWR.setText(weightAndReps.getText().toString());
                EditText editMax = (EditText) dialogViewEdit.findViewById(R.id.txtMaxED);
                editMax.setText(maxValue.getText().toString());
                EditText editDate = (EditText) dialogViewEdit.findViewById(R.id.txtDateED);
                editDate.setText(date.getText().toString());

                Button cancel =(Button) dialogViewEdit.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
                Button save =(Button) dialogViewEdit.findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
                cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                    builderE.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        EditText editName = (EditText) dialogViewEdit.findViewById(R.id.liftNameED);
                        EditText editNotes = (EditText) dialogViewEdit.findViewById(R.id.liftNotesED);
                        EditText editWR = (EditText) dialogViewEdit.findViewById(R.id.txtWRED);
                        EditText editMax = (EditText) dialogViewEdit.findViewById(R.id.txtMaxED);
                        EditText editDate = (EditText) dialogViewEdit.findViewById(R.id.txtDateED);

                        dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                        LiftSave liftSave = new LiftSave(longClickedItemLiftSave.getId() , String.valueOf(editName.getText()), String.valueOf(editMax.getText()), String.valueOf(editNotes.getText()), String.valueOf(editWR.getText()), String.valueOf(editDate.getText()));
                        dbHandler.updateLiftSave(liftSave);
                        LiftSaves.clear();
                        LiftSaves.addAll(dbHandler.getAllLiftSaves());
                        saveAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
                });
                builderE.setView(dialogViewEdit);
                builderE.show();
                break;
            case DELETE:
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity());
                builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this save?")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                                dbHandler.deleteLiftSave(longClickedItemLiftSave);
                                saveAdapter.remove(longClickedItemLiftSave);
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog dialogD = builder.create();
                dialogD.show();
                break;
                            }
                            return super.
                            onContextItemSelected(item);
                        }
        }
```

Comment: I'm a little confused about this one, but it seems that in the first section of `onContextItemSelected`, shouldn't you be using the data from `longClickedItemLiftSave` to populate the fields?

Comment: @DanielNugent yes, I'm trying to use that (`longClickedItemLiftSave`) data. Those `TextView`'s are those that are apart of each entry set by the `SaveListAdapter`. Maybe its not the best way to arrive at the `Strings`. Granted I wrote it before your suggestions on my other question.

Comment: Does the user have to long-click the item in order for the context menu to appear?

Comment: @DanielNugent yes, the long-click launches a `ContextMenu` the `ContextMenu` open the `Dialog`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that if `longClickedItemLiftSave` is getting populated correctly, you could change the code to this and it would fix it:

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case EDIT:
                final View dialogViewEdit = LayoutInflater.from(this.getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.edit_save, null, false);
                final AlertDialog builderE = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity()).create();

                /* not needed
                TextView liftName = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.liftName);
                TextView maxValue = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.maxValue);
                TextView weightAndReps = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.weightAndReps);
                TextView liftNotes = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.liftNotes);
                TextView date = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.todayDate);

                 */


                //Use values from longClickedItemLiftSave  
                EditText editName = (EditText) dialogViewEdit.findViewById(R.id.liftNameED);
                editName.setText(longClickedItemLiftSave.getLiftName());
                EditText editNotes = (EditText) dialogViewEdit.findViewById(R.id.liftNotesED);
                editNotes.setText(longClickedItemLiftSave.getLiftNotes());
                EditText editWR = (EditText) dialogViewEdit.findViewById(R.id.txtWRED);
                editWR.setText(longClickedItemLiftSave.getRepsAndWeight());
                EditText editMax = (EditText) dialogViewEdit.findViewById(R.id.txtMaxED);
                editMax.setText(longClickedItemLiftSave.getMaxValue());
                EditText editDate = (EditText) dialogViewEdit.findViewById(R.id.txtDateED);
                editDate.setText(longClickedItemLiftSave.getTodayDate());
```

Comment: Haha, I guess I've been confusing myself here. Daniel you're my hero. Thanks again.